# I partitioned a disk and now bios doesn't know which disk to boot from

Tags: boot, fdisk

I added another disk to my setup. I partitioned the entire disk to be ext4 with fdisk and mkfs.ext4. Now when I start the computer, it simply shows a blinking cursor.

When I remove the disk, the computer boots fine. Not sure why a newly partitioned disk would cause boot confusion.

I also have other disks I've added in the past, so I'm not sure what wouldd different.

Could it be that the new partition comes before the disk with the OS? That is, the one I recently added is /dev/sdb while the OS is one /dev/sdc?

Comment: In the UEFI or BIOS you have to put the bootdevice to the disk that is called 'sdc' in your Ubuntu. (What happened to 'sda' ?) The UEFI/BIOS tries to boot from the first harddisk (, which is 'sdb', since you don't mention 'sda') and the OS is not on that disk.

Comment: Correction to the above (assuming UEFI mode): The OS doesn't need to be in the same drive. The drive with the ESP is the one that should be in the first boot priority.

Comment: If your system wants to boot first drive, change ports that drives are connected into. Put boot drive into SATA0 and then data or other drives in higher numbered SATA ports. Drives normally are set by UEFI/BIOS in SATA port order. You may have to check manual to see which port is which. My motherboard had SATA 0 in middle of group of SATA ports. If M.2 drive, that may also disable a SATA port.

Comment: @oldfred That seemed to do it. Thanks!